# How to explicitly apply percent escapes to a URL in nginx?

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have the following configuration:

```
location ~ ^/((index\.php|robots\.txt|admin|static|uploads|api)(/.*)?)$ {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/$1?$args;
}
```

I want to apply percent escaping to `$1`, so e.g. `/admin/foo%20bar` would forward as `/admin/foo%20bar` and not as `/admin/foo bar`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Try to use [nginx http_set_misc_module#set_unescape_uri](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSetMiscModule#set_unescape_uri)

eg:

```
location ~ ^/((index\.php|robots\.txt|admin|static|uploads|api)(/.*)?)$ {
    set_unescape_uri $1;

    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/$1?$args;
}
```

Comment: Great, but do you know any other method without installing additional plugins for nginx? There are no OpenResty binary packages for Raspbian and I failed to compile it myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use set directive which keeps encoding intact or you can say re-encodes decoded uri.

```
location ~ ^/((index\.php|robots\.txt|admin|static|uploads|api)(/.*)?)$ {
    set $query $1;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/$query?$args;
}
```